# What means "proper" in this context: zero-mean complexrandom variables;

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, definition

Does anyone know what " zero-mean complex random variable" means?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Wikipedia section on proper complex RVs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_random_variable#Proper_complex_random_variables) It seems to mean having first and second moments be $0$, as well as having finite variance.

Comment: This answer is now updated -- the first google search was misleading.